# How to have a clean slice

Tags: modeling, modifiers, add-on

With the Booltool addon. Im slice the mesh to get a top part separate. Im looking for this type of battery opening.

[image]

[image]

I tried to add a sphere and with booltool i tried to slice the mesh. The mesh get extracted with extra edge and the base mesh got union with it. Any other cool way to have slice the mesh.

**[I tried this with booltool addon (gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgwFa.jpg)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your Boolean Modifier above your EdgeSplit modifier and move the cutter Sphere just a tiny bit in a y-direction so there are no overlapping vertices.

[image: Move boolean modifier above edge split modifier]

If you want a copy of your cutter then you can copy it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and in Object Properties under Viewport Display change Display As Textured.

[image: Display As Textured]

Comment: Thanks it solved. Im using 2.9 why i cant see the canvas (properties) https://imgur.com/a/A3wZnCF